# null value in column "installed_on" violates not-null constraint

Tags: flyway

We created a new database by coping from an older flyway managed database. (flyway version table also copied over)

Running flyway against this new database produces the following flyway error

Apr 24 19:00:19 ip-xx flyway: Unable to insert row for version '184' in Schema History table "public"."flyway_schema_history"
Apr 24 19:00:19 ip--xx flyway: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Apr 24 19:00:19 ip--xx flyway: SQL State  : 23502
Apr 24 19:00:19 ip--xx flyway: Error Code : 0
Apr 24 19:00:19 ip--xx flyway: Message    : ERROR: null value in column "installed_on" violates not-null constraint

Comment: Which version of flyway are you using now and which on the older database? Can you tell us which database you're using?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error occurred while upgrading from flyway version 5.x to 6.4.3.
The definition of *installed_on column* of the *flyway_schema_history table* (at least in PostgreSQL) has changed from:

```
installed_on timestamp NOT NULL;
```

to:

```
installed_on timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now ()
```

Adding `DEFAULT now()` on the existing table has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Flyway are you using, and has it changed when you moved database? Which database are you using?

If you could create an issue at github.com/flyway/flyway/issues with reproduction steps then the team will investigate for you.